# full calendar plugin not removing events

Tags: javascript

i'm using [full calendar plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/) v3 . the problem is removeEventSource function does not work when i specify parameter. i've tried to put Id, URL as parametres, and use refetchEvents but no luck.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource'); //working without parameters

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', 1); //does not work
```

array:

```
var  events = [
            {    id: 1,

                title: 'dinner',
                start: '2016-09-14',
                end: '2016-09-14'
            },
            {    id: 2,
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2016-09-10',
                end: '2016-09-10'
            },
            {   id: 3,
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2016-09-10',
                end: '2016-09-10'
            },
            {   id: 4,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00',
                end: '2016-09-09'
            }
        ]
```

intilize the calendar

```
 var calender = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
        navLinks: true, 
        selectable: true,
        droppable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); 
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        drop: function() {
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
        ,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events :  events
    });
```

click event

```
$('body').on('click','.fc-close',function(e){
    //alert('remove event');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', 1);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );



    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a bit confused over  `eventSources` and `events` , an evenSource is a collection of events so when you pass that `events` in the initialization a **default eventSource** is initialized with no `id` that's why it's only working when you don't pass any id.Correct way to pass eventSource is embed you events inside it and give an id to each eventSource item like below

```
var eventSrc = [
                 {  
                    id:1,
                    events : [{                             
                                id: 1,
                                title: 'dinner',
                                start: '2016-09-14',
                                end: '2016-09-14'
                              },
                              {    
                                id: 2,
                                title: 'All Day Event',
                                start: '2016-09-10',
                                end: '2016-09-10'
                             }]
                 },
                 {  
                    id:2,
                    events : [{                                 
                                id: 1,
                                title: 'camping',
                                start: '2016-08-14',
                                end: '2016-08-14'
                              },
                              {    
                                id: 2,
                                title: 'sports day',
                                start: '2016-08-10',
                                end: '2016-08-10'
                             }]
                 }
               ]
```

In initialization

```
var calender = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                            //other stuff
                                            eventSources : eventSrc
                                          });
```

Now just pass id of eventSource to remove it

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', 1);
```